# Pass an asp web control as a CommandArgument

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web app I have a series of ImageButtons. Upon clicking any of these ImageButtons, the ImageButton that was clicked needs to have it's image changed.

I would like one OnClick method that performs its action on the ImageButton that was clicked. Here is my attempt so far:
ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageToChange1" runat="server" OnClick="ChangeImage" CommandArgument="ImageToChange1"/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageToChange2" runat="server" OnClick="ChangeImage" CommandArgument="ImageToChange2"/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageToChange3" runat="server" OnClick="ChangeImage" CommandArgument ="ImageToChange3"/>
```

For my C# Code I want to do something like the following:

```
public void ChangeImage(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.CommandArgument.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Penguins.jpg";
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a more appropriate way to do this than using the "OnClick" event or if I can accomplish this by manipulating "e" or "sender" somehow. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ChangeImage, you can get the CommandArgument and the control as below

```
public void ChangeImage(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
      ImageButton imageButton = sender as ImageButton;
      string imageToChange = e.CommandArgument;
      //Then you can assign the appropreate image
      imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Penguins.jpg";

}
```